# I`m getting an error "[Errno 22] Invalid argument" while trying to open the file

Tags: python, function, readlines, invalid-argument

I am trying to write a function which takes a file and returns a list. But it doesn`t work. Instead it says:

'IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Python32\x07ssignment3\wordlist.txt''

when I am trying to run the module

```
words_file_name = 'C:\Python32\assignment3\wordlist.txt'
words_file = open(words_file_name, 'r')

def read_words(words_file):
    words_list = words_file.readlines()
    return words_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the backslashes or use a raw string literal. Otherwise, that `\a` is turning into `\x07`, which is the hex representation of the escape character `\a`. I'd recommend using raw strings for this so you don't have to deal with extra backslashes.

```
words_file_name = r'C:\Python32\assignment3\wordlist.txt'
                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by marking \a in your \assignement as \\a. Whenever you encounter \b, \n, \r, \t etc. in your directory path, Replace them with a double slash.